# progress monitor dialog calculating total time

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, osgi, eclipse-rcp, osgi-bundle

I would like to implement a progress monitor dialog in my application. The functionality is  to copy a large file/folder from one location to
another location winthin Windows. If we do copy and paste within windows, it might take approximately 7-10 mins.
When we are implementing through eclipse rcp progress monitor dialog, how do we calculate the total time for completing the task ?Because for smaller files it might take very less time and for bigger files it will huge time. So what is the advantage of Hard cording the `TOTAL_TIME = 10000.` over her?
Once the job is done, then we can say that it took around 7 or 8 mins. This is the confusion I have when I went through the following code.

I would be copying the based on the file size algorithm.

I got a sample example there total time is mentioned as `TOTAL_TIME = 10000.`

following is the sample code :

```java
public void run(IProgressMonitor monitor) throws InvocationTargetException,
      InterruptedException {
    monitor.beginTask("Running long running operation",
        indeterminate ? IProgressMonitor.UNKNOWN : TOTAL_TIME);
    for (int total = 0; total < TOTAL_TIME && !monitor.isCanceled(); total += INCREMENT) {
      Thread.sleep(INCREMENT);
      monitor.worked(INCREMENT);
      if (total == TOTAL_TIME / 2) monitor.subTask("Doing second half");
    }
    monitor.done();
    if (monitor.isCanceled())
        throw new InterruptedException("The long running operation was cancelled");
  }
}
```

Comment: If you could provide more details about how do you copy the file, it would be easier. You could try using file size related algorithm and copy contents, controlling how many bytes were copied. In this case it would be also possible to calculate time for the whole operation.

Comment: @Alexander Gavrilov I would be using file size algoritham

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could be used (it is just rough example, which can be improved in many ways):

```
        FileChannel src = null;
        FileChannel dest = null;
        try {
            src = new FileInputStream(file1).getChannel();
            dest = new FileOutputStream(file2).getChannel();

            int offset = 1024;
            long totalSize = src.size();
            long position = 0;

            int numberOfIterations = (int) (totalSize / offset);
            int currentIteration = 0;

            monitor.beginTask("Running long running operation", numberOfIterations);

            while (!monitor.isCanceled()) {
                long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                dest.transferFrom(src, position, position + offset);
                long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
                monitor.worked(currentIteration++);
                long timeElapsedPerOneIteration = (end - start) / 1000;
                monitor.setTaskName("Running long running operation. Time left: "
                    + ((timeElapsedPerOneIteration * numberOfIterations) - timeElapsedPerOneIteration * currentIteration)
                    + " seconds.");
                position += offset;
                if (position >= totalSize) {
                    monitor.done();
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // hanlde
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // hanlde
        } finally {
            if (src != null) {
                try {
                    src.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // hanlde
                }
            }
            if (dest != null) {
                try {
                    dest.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // hanlde
                }
            }
        }
```